# Defining new type composed of known types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, overloading

Suppose I want to define a new type that takes an int and a string. I know to define it like this:

`data Comp = Comp Int String`

But the problem with this notation is that when I have an instance of this type the instance is in the form of:

`Comp 45 "heloWorld"`

And I don't want that, I want that both these "parameters" of the datatype ( more like entries of a record), I want them separated by a character for example | or # instead of the whitespace. I don't want that character to do anything, it is just a notation I want to use. In this case,
`45#"hii"` 
is what i want instead of 
`45 "hii"`.
How do i need to tweak the definition of the datatype in order to do this? 
I plan to overload operators for this datatype so for example:
`45#"kkk" + 128#"a"` should be a valid operation.

Comment: For your example to work you need to implement `Num` for `Comp`. How should that work?

Comment: But if the only thing you want to do is `+`, I recommend using `<>` instead and making it a `Monoid` instead of a `Num`.

Answer (score 6):

You can just define an operator as an alias for your constructor:

```
data Comp = Comp Int String deriving Show

(#) :: Int -> String -> Comp
(#) = Comp
```

Now you can use `#` to construct your value:

```
λ: 45#"kkk"
Comp 45 "kkk"
```

Comment: Extra note: you can define an [infix constructor](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#infix-tycons) if you really want one, though the name has to start with a `:`.

Comment: Note that this stops working when the `MagicQuote` language extension is activated due to the unfortunate choice of the operator name.

Comment: @Rhymoid You mean `MagicHash`. And it will still work if you have a space in between: `45 # "kkk"`

Comment: thanks for your answer this works. the problem is now i want to use | instead of # as my operator. for some reason haskell wont compile the file if i use | but it compiles for #.. Any ideas?

Comment: @gonza1207, `|` (by itself) isn't a valid operator because it is used by the guard syntax.  You can't have any operator you want, there are some rules... (but you can have many more than in most languages!)

Answer (score 4):

You can define infix data constructors, but they must start with `:`.  So:

```
data Comp = Int :# String
```

If you intend the notation `45:#"kkk" + 128:#"a"` to work, you should also define it to have a tight precedence:

```
infix 9 :#
```

The slight advantage of using an infix constructor instead of @fjh's suggestion is that automatically derived `Read` and `Show` instances will use the `:#` notation, and you can pattern match using it as well:

```
thingy (n :# s) = ...
```

That said, it's really just a notational convenience, and @fjh's suggestion is also fine and commonly used.